# How to include first number to iterator class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

How to edit this class to obtain n0 in the PPP? I am not obtaining the initial number in the sequence. Thanks

```
class P():
    def __init__(self, n0):
        self.n = n0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.n == 1:
            raise StopIteration
        
        self.n = self.n - 1
        return self.n

nmax = 10
PP = P(nmax)

PPP = []

for j in PP:
    PPP.append(j) 

print(PPP)
```

Current output:

```
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Desired output:

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: The minimal fix would be `self.n = n0 + 1`, surely?

Comment: `self.n = n0+1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value before decrementing it

```
def __next__(self):
    if self.n == 1:
        raise StopIteration
    num = self.n
    self.n = self.n - 1
    return num

#[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I meant it generally, the sequence was just for simplification.

Comment: Won't this work for any sequence? You're returning the decremented value

Comment: I am sorry. I works. Thank you so much.

Comment: And how to obtain even the last number of sequence, please?